# Finland Mathematical Olympiad Problem 4, Number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

Define the sequence $a_{n}=n^{n}-(n-1)^{n+1}$ for positive integers $n$. Find all positive integers $m$ such that $a_n$ is eventually periodic modulo $m$.

**What I did**:
We can see that any $a_{n + t}$ will be congruent to $a_{n}$ modulo $m$ if $t = m \cdot \phi(m)$ for $\gcd(n,m) = 1$ and $\gcd(n + 1, m) = 1$.
This is sorted for $m$ being prime as then for any number being
of $pk$ form will have a period of $p$ and any other number will have a period of $p(p-1)$. My friend told me the powers of prime would work and even proved that $m$ can be anything. I think his proof might be wrong.

**Questions**:
Is my thinking correct? If yes, then any other numbers that not prime satisfy the conditions? If no, where is my mistake?
Can anyone point out the mistake or help me understand his proof?

His proof:

---

**Claim 1:** For any prime powers $p^a$, we have $a_n$ periodic mod $p^a$ for large enough $n$.

*Proof:*
Case 1: If $n \not\equiv \{0, 1\} \pmod{p}$:
In this case $n$ and $n - 1$ are coprime to $p^a$.
$\implies$ By Euler, $a_n \equiv a_{n + p^a \phi(p^a)} \pmod{p^a}$, so period $p^a \phi(p^a)$ for those.

Case 2: If $n \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$.
Let $n$ be large enough such that $n > a$, so $n^n$ would be a multiple of $p^a$:
Let $n' = n + p^a \phi(p^a)$ so that $n' > a$ as well:
Then since $n - 1, n' - 1$ are coprime to $p^a$, by Euler:
$\implies a_n \equiv n^n - (n - 1)^{n + 1} \equiv -(n - 1)^{n + 1} \equiv -(n' - 1)^{n' + 1} \pmod{p^a}$.
So period $p^a \phi(p^a)$ for those.

Case 3: If $n \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$:
Let $n > a$ be large enough, again. So $(n - 1)^{n + 1}$ is a multiple of $p^a$. Since $p \mid n - 1$.
Similarly, consider $n$ and $n' = n + p^a \phi(p^a)$. $n' > a$, so $(n' - 1)^{n' + 1} \equiv 0 \pmod{p^a}$.
$n', n$ are coprime to $p^a$, so by Euler: $a_n \equiv n^n + 0 \equiv (n')^{n'} + 0 \equiv a_{n'} \pmod{p^a}$. Done.

Hence, for $n > a$, we must have $a_n \equiv a_{n + p^a \phi(p^a)} \pmod{p^a}$ in all cases.

**Claim 2:** If $m_1, m_2$ are coprime and they both work, so as $m_1 m_2$.

*Proof:* from some point onward, they are both periodic. At that point onward, within the LCM of their period, $a_n$ would repeat the same pair of residue mod $m_1, m_2$, therefore the sequence of $a_n$ mod $m_1 m_2$ is also periodic.

Claim 1 and 2 together yields $m$ can be anything.

---

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Your proof is not well explained, could you a)restate it into a formal proof and b)explain how it concludes that some number cannot be prime?

Comment: Yes I will edit it

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a_%7Bn%7D%3Dn%5E%7Bn%7D-(n-1)%5E%7Bn%2B1%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aperiodic&p=1), there's the AoPS thread [a_n = n^n + (n - 1)^{n+1}, eventually periodic modulo m](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1912453p13100935).

Comment: Note that your first line need not be true for small $n$, especially in the case of prime powers.

Comment: @JohnOmielan 
I am not able to find a satisfiable answer there.

Comment: The formula produces these periodic patterns for 

\begin{align*}
m&\,(r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4,\cdots)\\
1&\,(0)\\
2&\,(1)\\
3&\,(1,0,2,1,1,1)\\
4&\,(1,3,3,1)\\
6&\,(1,3,5,1,1,1)\\
\end{align*}

Comment: I checked the proof of your friend. It is simple, straightforward, and correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is illegible. It is not possible to understand what $pk$ form is when neither $p$ nor $k$ is defined. I assume that $p$ is a prime integer and $k$ is some integer, then $pk$ would be every integer, but that goes against your conclusion that it can be only primes. And you also say that any other number would have period $p(p-1)$, but this means every number is periodic including powers of primes, etc.

But even if all of this was misinterpreted, you don't even prove that some number cannot be prime, just that some numbers can be, which is probably the big mistake, since it's not a finished proof. If the question asks for you to find *all* integers of $m$, then you need to show that any other integer outside of your conditions cannot be prime.

Your friends proof, on the other hand, is legible, formal, and correct.

To conclude, in the future if you encounter a similar problem you should:

1. Prove why a number $m$ cannot be prime, hence finishing your proof.
2. Write formal proofs so that people can understand them, or at the *very very* least define all the terms in your proof.
3. Make whatever work you show clear, and show the steps out when asking for help, so that when people read the proof they can point to the exact step where you went wrong.

Comment: Can you please explain his 2nd claim

Comment: The second claim doesn’t have much work so i can’t explain his argument perfectly, I would suggest asking him for more work. But is there a specific part you have a question on?

Comment: Can you explain how to prove that it works for all m after proving for any prime powers